# Custom BroadcastReceiver won't receive the broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have 5 fragments on a ViewPager (they're all in memory all the time, onPause() and such are never called while the containing Activity is on screen).

Anyway, I need to update one fragment (GroupsListFragment) depending on what's happening in another one (TimetableListFragment). I'm using LocalBroadcastManager and a BroadcastReceiver for this.

Now on to the relevant parts.
Registering for the broadcast Intent (severely abbreviated):

```
public class GroupsListFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
            mBroadCastReceiver = new UpdateGroupsReceiver(this);
            IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(UpdateGroupsReceiver.UPDATE_TIMETABLE_ACTION);
            Log.d("GroupsListFragment", "Registering for receiver with intentfilter:[action=" + iFilter.getAction(0) + "]");
            mBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mBroadCastReceiver, iFilter);
        }
}
```

Sending the broadcast (once again severely abbreviated):

```
public class TimetableListFragment extends Fragment {
    public void updateStatus() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UpdateGroupsReceiver.UPDATE_TIMETABLE_ACTION);
        mBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Sending broadcast with intent:[action=" + intent.getAction() + "]");
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `UpdateGroupsReceiver` never receives it (`onReceive()` is never fired).

Any advice on what might be the culprit?

Comment: what does updategroupsreciever look like? EDIT: NVM, probably not relevant... but I assume your log statements check out?

Comment: What do you do in onPause() for the GroupsListFragment? b/c you said that GroupsListFragment will probably be paused at this point.  Also, has it **ever** appeared on screen at this point?

Comment: i assume,put this.registerReceiver(BroadCastReceiver, IntentFilter); in onCreate() method and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code that is working well

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (myReceiver == null) {
        myReceiver = new UpdateGroupsReceiver(this);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
              UpdateGroupsReceiver.UPDATE_TIMETABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
}

public void updateStatus() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(UpdateGroupsReceiver.UPDATE_TIMETABLE_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

A runnig minimal example `testapp` can be found at https://github.com/k3b/EzTimeTracker/ under `BroadCastTest`.